# Android : How to get actual URL path for XML stored under res/xml?

Tags: android, android-xml

Hope the subject line makes it clear.

I want to get hold of the file path of the xml file which i store under the res/xml folder.

I'm aware of the InputStream approach by directly reading using the snippet.

... `getResources().getXml(R.raw.testxml);`

but my requirement is to just get the path of the stored file for the moment.

Any help appreciated

VATSAG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as to get full path of file stored in res/raw folder

```
String fullpath = "android.resource://" + 
                   YOUR_FULL_PACKAGE_NAME +
                   "/"+R.raw.testxml;
```